# Determine connection string based on a config value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I use `.Net Core`

I have a scenario where I will need to switch connection string to two different databases with identical schema based on departmentId.

I have a database named `Department1` where the older records reside and the management's decision is to move the various departments records to `Department2` periodically by updating a comma delimited toggle setting `DepartmentToggle` in our `Config` database. Basically, our ETL team will move the records to the new database and will update this setting after done. The long term plan is to move these database records to cloud. This is the first step in doing it.

So, if the toggle setting `DepartmentToggle` has value `"1,2,3"`, it means Departments 1, 2, 3 records are in `Department2`. So, I will have to first read the `DepartmentToggle` config value from `Config` database, check to see whether the DepartmentId is included in the toggle. If yes, the DepartmentContext must use the `Department2` connectionString. Below is my context class:

```
public partial class DepartmentContext : DbContext
{
    // Required for DI container
    public DepartmentContext() { }
    // Required for unit testing
    public DepartmentContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {}

    public virtual DbSet<Faculty> Faculties { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    ......
    //More DbSets

    //connectionString to change based on the DepartmentId
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Faculty>(entity => { });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: please let me know, if there's anything you'd want to get clarified further in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in the following way.

```
public class DepartmentContext : DbContext
{
    public DepartmentContext(
        IDepartmentRequestContext deptRequestContext, 
        IConnectionSelector connSelector) 
    : base(connSelector.GetConnectionString(deptRequestContext.SelectedDepartament))
    {
    }
}
```

Create a DepartmentRequestContext class with a Scoped lifetime registration (or PerRequest depending on your container). Then you can create a middleware or request handler, which will set the SelectedDepartment value based on your 1,2,3 loaded from the Config Db. Because SelectedDepartment resides in a Scoped instance the same value will be available in your Department context during it's creation.

Then in your ConnectionSelector you basically read IOptions based on the SelectedDepartment and retrieve appropriate connection string.

This whole solution is based upon the fact that the DepartmentContext should be created after the department is already known and cached in the middleware.